# How to snapshot the current frame of a mediaelement for UAP(windows 10)

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp

The basic Idea is this.
**I am writing a text in top of a paused video and I want to take a snapshot of it**
but the RenderTargetBitmap api doesnt work with video content and only renders the text with black backround. and the Screencapture api only works with the mobile device family and only renders the video and not the text.

Are there any other way to do this using pure c#? 
It is very simple. Draw a text on top of a paused media element and take a screenshot of it and save it to a file, why is it so hard to do this?

Comment: That's not been an easy task in many of the recent Microsoft client platform technologies (it's due to how the video is rendered). But, here's a sample that might get you started that was designed for Win 8.1: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-extensions-sample-7b466096

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible because of 2 reasons: 1) MediaElement's actual rendered video is not part of the visual tree, 2) DRM

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to participate in any manner of data manipulation associated with a MediaElement provided you have a Component that is wired into the Media Extensions video pipeline.

Examples are given in the following links:

https://github.com/mmaitre314/MediaReader
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/media-extensions-sample-7b466096

The first link provides a fully functional solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46313667/in-uwp-c-how-to-save-media-elements-current-frame/46316765#46316765) for a similar problem that I encountere writing an UWP app. In my case I needed a snapshot of the UI where could possibily be more than one MediaElement dinamically loaded with a bunch of other elements (Images, texts, ...).
The solution I came up with is not so linear but still working. When I need the snapshot:

- I extract the video frame and saved on disk for the time I needed it (you can find how in the other answer I wrote);
- I create a new dynamic Image with the saved framed e put on top of the MediaElement in the UI;
- Here you can create another "layer" with your text

At this point you can use RenderTargetBitmap to take your snapshot and dispose the Image on the UI. Don't forget to delete the file from disk like I do the first time....