# How to save media element's current frame?

Tags: c#, uwp

I am developing a media player like vlc. One of it's features is saving snapshot during playback. I am able to successfully save the snapshot of any element using rendertargetbitmap class, using the following c# code.

```
RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(); 
await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(RenderedGrid, width, height); 
RenderedImage.Source = renderTargetBitmap;
```

But it does not allow to capture media element. Please help me with a workaround. I guess, I am not sure, may it be possible by extracting a thumbnail from a specific position using position of StorageItemThumbnail Class. If even so, it will be a thumbnail not an image of current frame. Someone help please. It is essential feature of my app!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in a digital signage uwp app that I developed I had also a similar requirement. Searching the web on how I can do I found that in UWP you can't directly take a screenshot of a media element due to a protection policy (for example you could create a small app that captures all the frames of a video file without DRM management).

I came up with a workaround: I have the video file locally so I can extract a single frame at a certain point and save it to disk with the same dimensions of the video rendered on screen (in this way I had a full image of the frame to use later). To doing this I wrote this function:

```
private async Task<string> Capture(StorageFile file, TimeSpan timeOfFrame, Size imageDimension)
{
    if (file == null)
{
    return null;
}

//Get FrameWidth & FrameHeight
List<string> encodingPropertiesToRetrieve = new List<string>();
encodingPropertiesToRetrieve.Add("System.Video.FrameHeight");
encodingPropertiesToRetrieve.Add("System.Video.FrameWidth");
IDictionary<string, object> encodingProperties = await file.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(encodingPropertiesToRetrieve);
uint frameHeight = (uint)encodingProperties["System.Video.FrameHeight"];
uint frameWidth = (uint)encodingProperties["System.Video.FrameWidth"];

//Get image stream
var clip = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(file);
var composition = new MediaComposition();
composition.Clips.Add(clip);
var imageStream = await composition.GetThumbnailAsync(timeOfFrame, (int)frameWidth, (int)frameHeight, VideoFramePrecision.NearestFrame);

//Create BMP
var writableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)frameWidth, (int)frameHeight);
writableBitmap.SetSource(imageStream);

//Get stream from BMP
string mediaCaptureFileName = "IMG" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 4) + ".jpg";
var saveAsTarget = await CreateMediaFile(mediaCaptureFileName);
Stream stream = writableBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
byte[] pixels = new byte[(uint)stream.Length];
await stream.ReadAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);

using (var writeStream = await saveAsTarget.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, writeStream);
    encoder.SetPixelData(
        BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
        BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied,
        (uint)writableBitmap.PixelWidth,
        (uint)writableBitmap.PixelHeight,
        96,
        96,
        pixels);
    await encoder.FlushAsync();                
    using (var outputStream = writeStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
    {
        await outputStream.FlushAsync();
    }
}
return saveAsTarget.Name;
}
```

This function save the frame to disk as image and return his filename.
In my application I had more "widget" (some of those with images, some with video) so I used this function to get the video frames and put a new image on top of the media element with the same dimensions and a higher Canvas Z-Index in order to use `RenderTargetBitmap` for take the final screenshot.
It's not a clean solution but it was a workaround for `RenderTargetBitmap` not considering MediaElement.

***Edit:***
I forgot a reference to an internal function in my application so I canghed the previous code and the line `var file = await _mediaEngine.CreateMediaFile($"{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}.jpg");` is now `var file = await CreateMediaFile($"{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}.jpg");`

The async function CreateMediaFile(string fileName) simply create a new file on the disk:

```
public async Task<StorageFile> CreateMediaFile(string filename)
    {
        StorageFolder _mediaFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
        return await _mediaFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Agostini, Thanks for your help. It goes smooth until, _mediaEngine is not recognized!

Comment: @MgBhadurudeen I've updated my answer with the correct code. Now it should work as expected. Let me know!

Comment: Works amazing! Thanks Filippo Agostini, for sharing your great knowledge!

Comment: @FilippoAgostini why you don't create a sample for this in GitHub awesome work ;)

Comment: thank you @ShubhamSahu ! I will follow your sugestion and put something on GitHub in these days!

Comment: @FilippoAgostini and don't forget to update your github profile link in stackoverflow account