# How to get video properties (like video frame height and width) in a WPF application ( NET Core 6)

Tags: c#, wpf, media

I've loaded a file name with this simple file dialog code:

```
        public  string SelectFileFromFileExplorer()
        {
            var dialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            dialog.FileName = ""; 
            dialog.DefaultExt = ".mp4";

            bool? result = dialog.ShowDialog();

            if (result == true)
            {
                string filename = dialog.FileName;
                return filename;
            }
            else
            {
                return "File not found";
            }

        }
```

How do I get the frame width and height (and other properties) of the file in WPF? I've tried MediaToolkit (not compatible with .NET Core it seems), and I read some things about Shell32 but couldn't find any actual examples.

Comment: This question has very little to do with WPF, only the .Net framework version is relevant here.

Comment: You can utilize `StorageFile` of WinRT as well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46316765/3137337

Comment: @emoacht Thanks!